Does the Excel JavaScript API have a way to change the position of the grouped row expand/collapse button?
In the desktop version of Excel, the expand/collapse button can be moved to the top of grouped rows by going to data->outline->(more options) and unchecking "Summary Rows below Detail." Is there a way to do this programmatically via the Excel/Office-JS API? I haven't been able to find anything in the docs, and given that this feature seems to be missing in the web version of Excel, I'm guessing the answer is probably no, but just want to check.
